# Why this unregistred subdomain redirect to my wordpress?

Tags: dns, centos, powerdns

Im using powerdns in my VPS, yesterday in poweradmin I entered a subdomain to redirect to wordpress. Today, I decided to delete this subdomain, I delete it from poweradmin and its VirtualHost, but this subdomain continue redirecting to my wordpress. I've checked many times virtualhost and all is ok, I executed dig command, and it says this subdomain doesn't exist. I don't know what's happening, if I deleted the subdomain from poweradmin, it oughtn't redirect to wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All DNS servers cache queries. Until the TTL (time to live) of your record expires, some DNS servers will return the address you entered yesterday.